# How to import jsx file in tsx,

Tags: reactjs, import, jsx, tsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnoZP.png)

Red line is showing at the time of importing jsx file into tsx file.

to solve this issue just add, `"allowJs": true,` in tsconfig.json file ,

tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
  },
```

I was trying to import app.jsx file into main.tsx

Answer (score -1):

```js
 "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
  },
```

Now, my answer is cleared just adding, ```compilerOptions": {
"allowJs": true,
},

```
in tsconfig.json
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).